# Merge data files

Tags: r, social-networking

I have the following data frames in R:

```
Id   Class
@a    64
@b    7
@c    98
```

And the second data frame:

```
SOURCE    TARGET 
@d        @b
@c        @a
```

This is describes the nodes and the edges in a social network. The users (all with @ in front) belong to a specific community and the number is listed in column class. To analyse the connections between the columns I want to merge this data frames and create a new data frame looking like this:

```
SOURCE    TARGET    SOURCE.Class    TARGET.Class 
@a        @i        56               2
@f        @k        90               49
```

When I try `merge()` R stop responding and I need to terminate R. The data frames constitute 20000 (node file) and 30000 (edge file) rows.

Then I want to know how many records in a given source class have the same target class and percentage of connections between classes.

I will be so happy if someone could help me since I'm very new to R.

**EDIT:** 
I think I manage to create the columns by this code using `match()` instead of `merge()` (rt_node contain the columns "id", "class" and rt_node contain the columns "source","target"):

```
#match source in rt_edges with id in rt_node
match(rt_edges$Source,rt_nodes$id)

#match target in rt_edges with id in rt_node
match(rt_edges$Target,rt_nodes$id)

#create source_class 
rt_nodes$modularity_class[match(rt_edges$Source,rt_nodes$id)]
rt_edges$Source_Class=rt_nodes$modularity_class[match(rt_edges$Source,rt_nodes$id)]

#create target_class
rt_nodes$modularity_class[match(rt_edges$Target,rt_nodes$id)]
rt_edges$Target_Class=rt_nodes$modularity_class[match(rt_edges$Target,rt_nodes$id)]
```

Now I just need to figure out how I can find the percentage of connections in each class and the percentage of connections with other classes. Any tips on how to do that?

Comment: Please check the structure of the datasets. ie.. `str(dat1)`

Comment: Both datasets are data.frame with two variables and different number of rows.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to join (merge) data frames (inner, outer, left, right)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871/how-to-join-merge-data-frames-inner-outer-left-right)

Comment: `When I try merge() R stop responding...` could you add the code as well?

Comment: These are two questions. (1) Why isn't `merge` working, Here, the code causing problems should be shown.  (2) _How many records in a given source class have the same target class and percentage of connections between classes_ This should be posted as a separate question giving the expected result and matching sample data. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Question 1: Merge

This requires two separate join operations: An initial join of `rt_edges` with `rt_nodes` on `Target` and a subsequent join of the intermediate result with `rt_nodes` on `Source`. In addition, all rows of `rt_edges` should appear in the result.

The approach below uses `data.table`. (I've adopted the naming of variables and columns the OP has used in the edited code of his Q but note that this is inconsistent to the sample data given by the OP.)

### Reading data

```
library(data.table)
rt_nodes <- fread(
  "id   Class
  @a    64
  @b    7
  @c    98
  @d    23
  @f    59")
rt_edges <-fread(
  "Source    Target 
  @d        @b
  @c        @a
  @a        @e")
```

Note that additional rows have been added to the sample data provided by the OP to demonstrate the effect of

- a node (`@f`) not involved in an edge  and
- an edge (`@a -> @e`) where one id is missing from `rt_nodes`.

### Twofold join

By default, joins in `data.table` are right joins. Therefore, `rt_edges` appears on the right side.

```
result <- rt_nodes[rt_nodes[rt_edges, on = c(id = "Target")], on = c(id = "Source")]

# rename columns
setnames(result, c("Source", "Source.Class", "Target", "Target.Class"))

result
#   Source Source.Class Target Target.Class
#1:     @d           23     @b            7
#2:     @c           98     @a           64
#3:     @a           64     @e           NA
```

All three edges appear in the result. The `NA` indicates that `@e` is missing from `rt_nodes`.

## Question 2

The OP has included a second question (and has also created [a new post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43293369/count-occurrence-in-one-variable-based-on-another) in the meantime)

> Then I want to know how many records in a given source class have the same target class and percentage of connections between classes.

```
result[, .(.N, share_of_occurrence_in_Target.Class = sum(Source.Class == Target.Class)/.N), 
       by = Source.Class]
#   Source.Class N share_of_occurrence_in_Target.Classs
#1:           23 1                                    0
#2:           98 1                                    0
#3:           64 1                                   NA
```

The counts are 1 and the shares are 0 here because the sample data don't include enough cases of matching classes. However, the code has been verified to work with the data provided in [the other post of the OP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43293369/count-occurrence-in-one-variable-based-on-another).