# Count occurrence in one variable based on another

Tags: r

I have the following structured table (as an example):

```
   Class 1    Class 2
1   1           1
2   1           1
3   1           1
4   1           2
5   3           3
6   3           3
7   3           4
8   4           4
```

I want to count how many times in a given Class 1 the same value appear in Class 2 and display this as a percentage value. Also group class 1. So I would want the result to be something like this:

```
 Class 1     n_class1    Percentage of occurrence in class 2 
1   1           4                  0.75
2   3           3                  0.666
3   4           1                  1.0
```

I have read a lot about the dplyr package and think the solution can be in there, and also looked at many examples but have not yet found a solution. I'm new to programming so don't have the natural programmer thinking yet, hope someone can give me tips on how to to this.

I have manage to get the `n_class1` by using group by but struggling to get the the percentage of occurrence in class 2.

Comment: use your group by on class 2 then `percentage[i] = n_class2[i] / n_class1[i]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do this by creating a new column `in.class1` with `mutate`:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(
    class1 = rep(c(1, 3, 4), c(4, 3, 1)),
    class2 = rep(c(1, 2, 3, 4), c(3, 1, 2, 2))
)

df %>%
    mutate(in.class1 = class2 == class1) %>%
    group_by(class1) %>%
    summarise(n_class1 = n(),
              class2_percentile = sum(in.class1) / n()
    )

# # A tibble: 3 × 3
#   class1 n_class1 class2_percentile
#    <dbl>    <int>             <dbl>
# 1      1        4         0.7500000
# 2      3        3         0.6666667
# 3      4        1         1.0000000
```

As suggested by Jaap in comment, this could be simplified to:

```
df %>%
    group_by(class1) %>%
    summarise(
        n_class1 = n(),
        class2_percentile = sum(class1 == class2) / n())
```

Comment: no need for the mutate step, just `df %>% group_by(Class1) %>% summarise(n = n(), perc = sum(Class1 == Class2)/n)` gives the same result

Comment: @Jaap, that's better. I would like to add this into answer.

Comment: Could I also display in an additional column how many different class 2 is connected to every class 1?

Comment: @staanR, you can try `n_class2_in_class1 = sum(class1 == class2)` to `summarize`

Answer (score 1):

The question has already been asked as part of [a larger question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43275478/3817004) the OP has asked before where it has been answered using `data.table`.

## Read data

```
library(data.table)
cl <- fread(
  "id   Class1    Class2
  1   1           1
  2   1           1
  3   1           1
  4   1           2
  5   3           3
  6   3           3
  7   3           4
  8   4           4"
)
```

## Aggregate

```
cl[, .(.N, share_of_occurence_in_Class2 = sum(Class1 == Class2)/.N), by = Class1]
#   Class1 N share_of_occurence_in_Class2
#1:      1 4                    0.7500000
#2:      3 3                    0.6666667
#3:      4 1                    1.0000000
```